# Magento - Layout

Tags: magento

```
<block type="catalog/product_compare_sidebar" before="cart_sidebar" name="catalog.compare.sidebar" template="catalog/product/compare/sidebar.phtml"/>
<block type="catalog/product_list"...>
```

I have studyed http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/, it mention that a type attribute, which defines the block class name.

In the code above, catalog/product_compare_sidebar and catalog/product_list should be a block class, so, where is the location of the php file that declared these block(Any hint from "catalog/product_compare_sidebar" and "catalog/product_list")?

There are many block type, how can I know which block type is available and how to choose which block type is suitable for the existing block?

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the association:

```
catalog/product_compare_sidebar => /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/Compare/Sidebar.php
catalog/product_list => app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php
```

If you use eclipse PDT, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:
*Catalog*Product_Compare_Sidebar to find the first class.

UPDATE: Searching for "class *Block*" will give you all the available block types.
If you use eclipse PDT, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:
*Block* .
The paragraph at the end of your link describes the most important one fairly well. Personnaly, I often create my own type and inherit from Mage_Core_Block_Template , or use it directly.

UPDATE_2: In Mage_Core_Block_Abstract, you can see this method

```
/**
 * Set block attribute value
 *
 * Wrapper for method "setData"
 *
 * @param   string $name
 * @param   mixed $value
 * @return  Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
 */
public function setAttribute($name, $value=null)
{
    return $this->setData($name, $value);
}
```

I think it must be called on each xml attribute somewhere. To know where, simply put a breakpoint here, or die here and look at the stack trace.

Comment: Thanks for the information, but how about "There are many block type, how can I know which block type is available and how to choose which block type is suitable for the existing block?"

Comment: Thanks you, one more thing "{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="5"template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}", how come it can have the attribute category_id?

Comment: That's to tell the block that it should present only the products from category with ID=5.

Comment: I know it present category from id=5, but where is this attribute is Magento default attribute or it can be created by other developer)?

Comment: There is no strict grammar to the block definitions, so in theory you can add any data you want in that format. You may need to define a setX method for that data.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Why I use [category_id="5"] works, and [cat_id="5"] or [id="5"] not work? How to determine which attribute is works? Thanks you